# File_get_contents doesnt work for image php

Tags: php

I'm trying to move an image using `file_get_contents`, but it doesn`t move it.

```
  $im= file_get_contents("../image/pic.jpg");
   $path="../image/post/image.jpg";


      If(file_exists($path)){}else{
          $create= mkdir("../image/post/");
       }

      move_uploaded_file($im,$path);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: move_uploaded_file is for an uploaded file that was sent via POST. If the file is already stored locally, move_uploaded_file is not the right function. You'd be looking for rename.

Comment: Almost everything with this code is wrong. Functions used in the code are not meant to do what you expect them to do. You really should consider having a look at functions' documentation before using them.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to `move_uploaded_file()` must both be filenames. `$im` is not a filename, it's the contents of `pic.jpg`.

Use `file_put_contents()` to write to a file:

```
file_put_contents($path, $im);
```

But there's no need to read the file into a variable in the first place. You can use the `copy()` function to copy one file to another.

```
copy("../image/pic.jpg", $path);
```